# Optimizar velocidad de carga de sitio web - Recomendaciones de Google

Tags: javascript, html, optimización, rendimiento

Hola tengo un sitio web y usando la herramienta de testeo de velocidad de google me arrojo las siguientes recomendaciones:

> - Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
> - Optimize images
> - Leverage browser caching

¿Podrían explicarme la primera? no logro entenderla, moví todos los script de mi pagina (js)del head al pie de body, pero resulto que ese no era el tema, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Ya consultaste la documentación? Está en español y es bastante clara: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS o en todo caso, ¿podrías hacer tu pregunta más específica, explicando qué has hecho y qué esperas obtener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el render-blocking creo que se refieren a todo lo que hace que le cueste cargar a una página web.

Lo que has hecho de mover el js del head al pie del body permite cargar el contenido antes que los scripts. Esta técnica esta incluida en una serie de pautas que se recomiendan para evitar el render-blocking.

Las técnicas más recomendadas son las siguientes:

- Que la página inicialmente solo cargue la parte que ve el usuario y luego progresivamente cargue el resto de la página.
- Si la página no utiliza grandes funcionalidades de JS, es recomendable no utilizar librerías o frameworks que puedan elevar el tiempo de carga.
- También la técnica que has usado de mover la llamada a los JS del HEAD al pie del BODY no es suficiente. Lo ideal sería que primero se ejecutara el contenido de la página y luego los archivos JS. Esto puedes hacerlo con un "onload" pero no me parece la opción más adecuada porque acaba interfiriendo en el rendimiento de la página.

He estado indagando y he encontrado este código.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "defer.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

La diferencia entre esto y un "onload", es que el "onload" carga el fichero y hasta que la página se muestra totalmente no ejecuta el código pero entre tanto se han gastado recursos en cargarlo. La solución del código espera a que la página se haya cargado para cargar y ejecutar el fichero.

Todo esto contribuye a que la página valla más rápida, sin duda también el pilar más importante es un código ligero y limpio.

Te dejo también los enlaces donde he sacado información por si quieres hecharles un ojo:
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking.html

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html

Comment: muchas gracias por la información esta muy completa :)